# Case insensitive key for hashmap kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I have a hashmap with string as key and integer as value. I want the keys to be case insensitive.

```kotlin
val items = HashMap<String, Int>()
    items["key1"] = 90
    items["Key1"] = 80
    items["C"] = 70
    for ((k, v) in items) {
        println("$k = $v")
    }
```

This takes key1 and Key1 as separate entries

Comment: One option is creating our own object, extend `HashMap` and lower case key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this, you would need either to provide some extension function that would put and get the entry in some defined way (e.g. using every time `lowercase()` String's method) keeping keys case insensitive

```
fun HashMap<String, Int>.putInsensitive(k: String, v: Int) {
    this[k.lowercase()] = v
}

fun HashMap<String, Int>.getInsensitive(k: String, v: Int): Int? = this[k.lowercase()]
```

or provide your own `Map` interface implementation (it could even inherit from HashMap)

```
class InsensitiveHashMap<V> : HashMap<String, V>() {
    override fun put(key: String, value: V): V? = super.put(key.lowercase(), value)
    
    override fun get(key: String): V? = return super.get(key.lowercase())
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Although you can fake this with an extension to HashMap (as mentioned in another answer), I don't think that's a good solution: in order to make the map's behaviour fully consistent, you'd probably need to override lots of methods.  (For example, it would be hard to ensure that it maintained the case-insensitivity if you update the map via its [keySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--).  And there are probably many more gotchas along the way.)

In most cases, you don't really need a `HashMap` specifically — you just need a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementation.  And so an alternative is to **use another type of map that lets you provide your own [`Comparator`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparator/)**, e.g.:

```
val items = TreeMap<String, Int>{ a, b -> 
    a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase())
}
```

[`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is an implementation of [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) — a special type of `Map` that keeps its keys in order: either their natural ordering, or one you provide.  In this case, I've given a simple `Comparator` implementation which compares the lower-case versions of the two strings.

With this definition, the rest of the code in the question runs fine, and prints out:

```
C = 70
key1 = 80
```

…i.e. it has recognised that "Key1" should be treated the same as "key1", and updated that value instead of adding a new one.  I think this is the behaviour you want.

You don't need to take account of the fact that the map is sorted; that's just an added bonus.  You can still treat it like any other `Map` implementation, and everything should work.

(This is yet another example of why it's better to program to the interface, not the implementation.  If you write code that can use any `Map` implementation, you can give it a `HashMap` or a `TreeMap` or any other sort of map without any changes.)

Comment: Yup, if you're targeting the JVM, this is often the way to go. One suggestion would be to use `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`, a pre-defined comparator that's more efficient than converting to lowercase before each comparison: `TreeMap<String, Int>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`

Comment: Problem arises where you are not the one responsible for creating the instance of the TreeMap. You can't set the comparator outside of initialization. An example uses case is when serializing payload into data fields.

Answer (score 2):

A variation on the answer by @m.antkowicz, you can actually "override" the get / put operators on `HashMap` itself (and make it into a fantastic footgun):

```kotlin
operator fun HashMap<String, Int>.get(k: String): Int? = this[k.toLowerCase()]
operator fun HashMap<String, Int>.set(k: String, v: Int): Int? {
    val originalK = this[k.toLowerCase()]
    this.put(k.toLowerCase(), v )
    return originalK
}
```

So now you can:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val items = HashMap<String, Int>()
    items["key1"] = 90
    items["Key1"] = 80
    items["C"] = 70

    for ((k, v) in items) {
        println("$k = $v")
    }
// Prints:
//    key1 = 80
//    c = 70
}
```